# An error occurred when installing using npm and npx

Tags: javascript, npm, installation, node-modules, package.json

I have tried all the suggestions from chatgpt but it still doesn't work.

npm ERR! semver.parse is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\agung\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-11T07_47_07_434Z-debug-0.log

I have deleted node_modules and package-lock.json, I have reinstalled npm, ran the command "npm install --force" . still doesn't work either.

Comment: what version of npm and node?

Comment: i'm using node version v20.10.0 and npm 10.2.5

Comment: Seems right. Winder if it's something in your package.json

Comment: what should I fix in my package.json

Comment: if the problem is in package.json, then fix what the problem is in package.json I guess

Comment: Could you share the log on your post by editing? That might help people trying to answer.